# order form inside iFrame, session breaks (third party)

Tags: php, session, iframe

I'm trying to build an orderform which others can use within an Iframe on their website. Later I want to add this form to facebook.

My current form uses a session to bind the ordered products to the user, but if I disable third party cookies in Internet Explorer I can't order anything. The session ID is changing. 
During last steps I ask the user to login and bind an email address to the current session.

I prefer to keep using sessions, so when someone leaves my page, the ordered items are still in their chart. What is best approach to still use sessions inside my iframe?

Thanks for everyones help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A visitor accessing your web site is assigned a unique id, the so-called session id. This is either stored in a cookie on the user side or is propagated in the URL.

[Sessions: Introduction](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php)

So this means that if cookies are disabled, you need to propagate a session id into the URL. For example:

```
<a href="checkout.php?<?php echo htmlspecialchars(SID); ?>">Checkout</a>
```

Now the session id will be passed along even if the user has cookies disabled. It is up to you save the users cart into a database or something for when they completely leave your website. Afaik, sessions are always completely destroyed when a user leaves.

More info on passing the session id can be found here: [Passing the Session ID](http://php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php)

Comment: Thx for your help Icecub.. I added an unique id of 24 characters to the URL, to keep track of the session within Iframes.

Comment: @user3278918 No problem. If my answer has helped you solve the issue, please accept it. It's a way to show your appreciation to the person that helped you out as well as making sure your question doesn't remain unanswered forever.

Comment: @user3278918 please take care of your questions with upvotes and green check marks. Some of us research for a minute that before answering questions (like your new one). Thx

Comment: Thx Drew, if i have a question I do a lot of research before I ask it. I wish I could upvoted the answer from Icecub before, but I didn't have enough reputation to vote. Now I have with my next question. If u think i didn't do my research, please give me the link where the answer of my new question is...

Comment: @user3278918 What Drew ment was that some members of this website check if users take care of their questions before even attempting to help them out. Although it does require 15 reputation to upvote, marking the green check doesn't. You can do that as a new member. Anyway, thanks for showing me your appreciation :)

Comment: Icecub, thx. I didn't know that. I'm everyday on this website... most of my problems are already answered in other posts. Can u maybe help me with my last question?